# Стиль контролов в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Уже третий день бьюсь. Написал триггер для кнопки:

```
Style x:Key="SearchButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Остановить поиск"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Использую:

```
<Button Name="FindApp" Content="Найти приложения" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Click="FindApp_Click" Style="{StaticResource SearchButtonStyle}"/>
```

Никакой реакции.

В чём может быть дело?

Задаю Content в Style:

```
<Style x:Key="SearchButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Найти приложения"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Остановить поиск"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Найти приложения"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


<Button x:Name="FindApp" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Click="FindApp_Click" Style="{StaticResource SearchButtonStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Изначальный Content нужно также устанавливать через стиль:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FindAppButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Найти приложения"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Остановить поиск"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource FindAppButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Всё-равно не работает

Comment: @Сергей: Должно работать. Вы убрали `Content="Найти приложения"` из вашего XAML?

Comment: Да, я немного поменял триггер, но суть не изменилась, сейчас кину код.

Comment: @Сергей: Для `Tag` работает не так, т. к. его тип — `object`, а не `bool`, поэтому ваше значение `Property="Tag" Value="true"` было проинтерпретировано как строка `"true"`, а не значение. Попробуйте сделать точно так, как в рекомендации автора ответа.

Comment: @Сергей: http://pastebin.com/t0WFHPir

Comment: Сколько я интересного пропустил. @Сергей, заработало?